# How to label a textbullet with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, bullets

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[table,dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[red] at (6.6, 2.7) {\textbullet};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will produce a text-bullet. How to label that bullet?

I tried with:

```
\node[red] at (6.6, 2.7) {\textbullet}\q;
```

but got a compilation error. If I just do {q}, then I just get a red `q`.

Comment: Do you want to add text next to or below to the `\textbullet`? If yes, did you try `\node[red] at (6.6, 2.7) {\textbullet Your text goes here}`?

Comment: Oh that works, didn't think of that syntax. If possible @StefanBraun, I would like it to lay below the point. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions for you, the first one uses a line break, the second the `positioning` library of tikz.

```
\documentclass{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[red,align=center] at (6.6, 2.7) {\textbullet \\ Your Text is here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[red](dot) at (6.6, 2.7) {\textbullet};
       \node[below=0cm of dot]  {Your Text is here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```